# User input from Pysimplegui to store in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pysimplegui

I'm quite new into PysimpleGUI and Pandas dataframe

i am trying to get user input values from the GUI and store in the pandas dataframe, the data eventually will export to a excel file.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg


rfpwra=[]

sg.theme('DarkTeal9')
pass_fail=["PASS","FAIL"]
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please INPUT reading from Power Meter:')],
    [sg.Text('Enable "RF AMP x enable" then wait 1 minute\nPASS/FAIL?',size=(30,3)),sg.Listbox(pass_fail,size=(10,len(pass_fail)),key='-PF-')],
    [sg.Text('Read RF Amp Temp C below 60C.\nRecord the temperature:',size=(30,4)),sg.InputText(default_text='T0',size=(15,1),key='rfpwra')],
    [sg.Text("Enable 'AMOD' and write FMOD=170MHz, then adjust trimpot to until the power meter reads between 13.1 and 13.2\nPlease Input reading:",size=(50,4)) ,sg.InputText(default_text='RF_PWR',size=(15,1),key='rfpwra')],
    [sg.Text("Type at Norm.Freq 0 float '140' then click 'Write' and wait 1 minute\nthen record temperature at RF Amp Temps.C less than 90C\nRecord Temeprature Reading :",size=(50,4)) ,sg.InputText(default_text='Temp',size=(15,1),key='rfpwra')],
    [sg.Text("Measured RF power between 11W to 15W\nRecord Power Reading:",size=(50,3)) ,sg.InputText(default_text='RF_PWR',size=(15,1),key='rfpwra')],
    [sg.Submit(),sg.Button('Next',key='Next'),sg.Exit()]
    ]

window=sg.Window('ES-7521-G Report',layout,size=(500,500))

a=range(4)
df=pd.DataFrame({'rfpwrA':rfpwra},index=a)

while True:
    event,values=window.read()  
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event =='Exit':
        break  
    if event == 'Submit':
        print(df)
    if event == 'Next':
        break
window.close()
```

The error i'm getting is as below

```
ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (4)
```

what did i do wrong ?

Comment: Empty data passed with indices specified for `rfpwra=[]; a=range(4); df=pd.DataFrame({'rfpwrA':rfpwra},index=a)`

Comment: Thank you very much, but my value key in is not stored in the 'rfpwra' array, Any suggestion for this ?

Comment: You can refer it to any list with length 4 if no data at this moment.

Comment: i found out my data need to append in the array then it will store, thank you for the info.
For the ` rfpwra=[ ] ` i add in ` ' '`so python know it is a blank list